# How do I get a table to display images

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

I am building a table in Seaside (Using VisualAge Smalltalk). I would like to have each table row have an image as well as text data. This what the method looks like:

where `PSIni getImageUrl` returns the main part of the `url`. The final `url` looks like
http://www.totallyobjects.com/images/pennstadt//15.jpg

Can anyone point me as to how to get this done please?

```
 makeData: html usingMethod: aMethod

|tableData headingList methodList|

tableData := self perform: aMethod.
headingList := self headingList.
methodList := self methodList.

html table: [ 
    html tableRow: [ 
        headingList do: [ :each | html 
            tableHeading: each 
        ]
    ].
    tableData do: [ :one |          
        html tableRow: [
            methodList do: [ :each | 
                each = #image ifTrue: [ 
                    html tableData: (self showImageFor: one id using: html)
                ] ifFalse: [ 
                    html tableData: (one perform: each)                        
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

`(self showImageFor:  one id using: html)` obviously doesn't work. This method looks like this:

`showImageFor: anID using: html`

`html image width: 200;  url:  PSIni getImageURL, '/', anID printString, '.jpg'`

where `PSIni getImageUrl` returns the main part of the `url`.

The final `url` looks like:
http://www.totallyobjects.com/images/pennstadt/15.jpg
and should result in that image appearing in one element of a table row.

Comment: Why the `url` has the first time around "//" the second time "/" just before `15.jpg`?

Comment: Typing error. David

Comment: Ok,  Please upvote the answer and accept it if it suits your needs - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

You need to nest the brushes:

```
html tableData: [ (self showImageFor: one id using: html) ]
```

It's explained in depth in the book: http://book.seaside.st/book/fundamentals/rendering-components

Comment: Thank you. I should have remembered that. It works now.